# Cambiar tamaño de las columnas de una tabla en itextSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itextsharp

Buen dia,

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion para el calzado, el cual al terminar un pedido exportar un pdf con la toda la información obtenida de un formulario, lo que pretendo es que un datagridview sea pasado al pdf con el mismo tamaño de las celdas que se observa en el formulario, ya lo he logrado pero el tamaño de las celdas no es que el pretendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que pretendo hacer es que se vea maso menos de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es: ¿como puedo manipular el tamaño de las celdas?, estoy usando itextsharp.

Mi codigo es el siguiente para crear la tabla del DataGridView:

```
 PdfPTable tabla2 = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
            tabla2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
                cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 250);
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                tabla2.AddCell(cell);
            }

            //DATOS

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {


                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {

                    PdfPCell si = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString()));
                    si.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    tabla2.AddCell(si);
                }



            }
            pdfdoc.Add(tabla2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando declaras la tabla puedes declarar el ancho de celdas mediante:

```
//pseudo codigo 
private void TablaX(){
     PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
            //tamano de 500
            table.TotalWidth = 500f;
            //ancho sin variacion
            table.LockedWidth = true;

            //proporcion relativa - 1/3 y 2/3
            float[] widths = new float[] { 1f, 2f };
            table.SetWidths(widths);
            table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            //espacio antes y despues de la tabla
            table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
            table.SpacingAfter = 30f;

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tallas"));
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            // datos de prueab:
            for (int i = 0; i < DummySeed.Info.Count; i++)
            {
                table.AddCell(DummySeed.Info[i].Id.ToString());
                table.AddCell(DummySeed.Info[i].Name);
            }

            return table;
        }
```

saludos

Comment: Excelente amigo, gracias :D